# How to get ReactJs to work with FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm having a hard time getting [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) to work properly with ReactJs. The calendar shows up but it does not look correct and passing in arguments to `$("#calendar").fullCalendar()` does NOT do anything as you can see from the image below. *(should have day 6 - 8 highlighted green)*
[image]

So I started out with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) that just jump starts the project for me with all of the needed dependencies such as Babel and what not.

Then made 2 very simple React classes like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'moment/min/moment.min.js';

import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.min.css';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js';


class Calendar extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    const { calendar } = this.refs;

    $(calendar).fullCalendar({events: this.props.events});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref='calendar'></div>
    );
  }

}


class App extends Component {
  render() {

    let events = [
      {
        start: '2017-01-06',
        end: '2017-01-08',
        rendering: 'background',
        color: '#00FF00'
      },
    ]

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar events={events} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have no clue where the mistake is so I did what anyone would do and google around to see if someone has already ran into this issue and I came across [this short video tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-using-react-with-the-fullcalendar-jquery-plugin) on exactly this and still does not work properly.

Here is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "cal-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.8.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fullcalendar": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Iv'e tried everything I could think of and still no luck, help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

creator of that video here. I'd remove that call to `import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.min.css';`, because it's most likely overriding the CSS of the stylesheet before it.

Comment: One quick question, Redux store update does not reflect on calendar. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @LucasSantos i am also have this same issue, the events are not works here..plz give informations about that.......

Comment: Redux store not updating it. Any solution for this?

Comment: @MuneemHabib and others, you want to move `events` to the props and then map the state of events from Redux to the props and pass that in.

Comment: i want to filter resources. I use remove resources an then adrescources method but its not working

Answer (score 2):

The latest version v4 of Fullcalendar.io now has ReactJS documentation. I would use the React Components recommended by the FullCalendar creators:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

> FullCalendar seamlessly integrates with the React JavaScript
> framework. It provides a component that exactly matches the
> functionality of FullCalendar’s standard API.
>
> This component is built and maintained by Josh Ruff of Sardius Media
> in partnership with the maintainers of FullCalendar. It is the
> official React connector, released under an MIT license, the same
> license the standard version of FullCalendar uses.

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar now provides a [React wrapper](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react), and it works nicely with Create React App. Instead of importing CSS via Sass, you can import them directly like so:

```
import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css"
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css"
```